# Given a method value, get receiver object

Tags: go

Is there a way in Go, to get the receiver object from a method value?

For example, is there any such `MagicFunc` that would make the following program output the string `my info` from the underlying Foo instance.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    A string
}

func (foo *Foo) Bar() string {
    return "bar"
}

func MyFunc(val interface{}) {
    i := MagicFunc(val)
    f := i.(Foo)
    fmt.Println(f.A)
}

func main() {
    f := Foo{A: "my info"}
    MyFunc(f.Bar)
}
```

Comment: But a note to the OP: what problem are you actually trying to solve? There's probably a different solution. This looks like an XY Problem (I made the same comment on the possible duplicate)

Comment: It's impossible to write `MagicFunc` as specified, even when using the unsafe package and making assumptions about memory layout, interfaces and method values.  It might be possible to a function that works like this: `var f Foo; MagicFunc(val, &f)`, but it will be fragile.  What is the higher-level problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This is pretty close to the problem I was trying to solve. I was looking to create a mock/assertion framework that could assert method calls on mock objects via method values (instead of e.g. using strings with the method name). This explains why nobody's done it this way before :) If you have any ideas around this I'm open to it, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to get the method's receiver instance.

The most you can get is the receiver's type if you use a *method expression* instead of *method value* but that won't help you get the `my info` string.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to deep-dive into this a bit and soon found this document: https://golang.org/s/go11func

As describe there, when `MyFunc` is entered `val` doesn't contain a reference to f.Bar but rather to a special function with the signature `func() string`. That function knows that it can retrieve the orignal f pointer by checking the well-known `R0` register (in the example. On amd64 it appears to be `dx`, but that's an implementation detail obviously).

Thus there's no way to do this without using implementation specific assembly code, which would be very fragile.